# Create ipa for testing on device using iPhone Packager

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, actionscript-3, itunes, package

i'm following [Christian Cantrell guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/packager-for-iphone-refresher.html) for packaging AS3 application for iPhone, but i can't find a way to use the packager for creating an app for testing on device. I've tried with -target ipa-test and -target ipa-app-store but when i try to upload my app on the iPad, iTunes throws an error sayng that i'm not allowed. I've done a simple test using the Packager bundled width CS5 (with the same certificates) and everything gone right.

Is is possible to use CS5 Packager for Flex project ? (i know that flex isn't optimized for mobile)

Thanks

Comment: The "Common Knowledge" is that it is not possible to build an iPhone app using Flex tools [yet].  Christian's blog post is the first time I've heard someone insinuate otherwise. I had no idea there were command line tools.  I though that to test something on your apple device you needed to join the Apple Developer program, though. Christian's post left a lot of confusion in my mind. Hopefully we'll hear more about this at 360|Flex in DC in 9 days. I think he is keynoting.

Comment: Flex is not suggested for mobile app because it's not optimized and doesn't handle multitouch but in the end it's just a normal swf. To test your app into the device you have to join Apple developer program, otherwise you can't have certificates to pass to pfi

Comment: You could always jailbreak your iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i've found the answer myself, the problem was the file descriptor *-app.xml. I've opened the one generated from Flash and copied few parameters

1. First the  section now reflect exactly the app id in the certificate obtained from Apple
2. Added some options about visualization (don't think that they really metter) fullscreen, aspectRatio, renderMode, autoOrients
3. Specify the device (iPad in this case) adding a new tag before /application

   <iPhone>
   <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[<key>UIDeviceFamily</key><array><string>2</string></array>]]></InfoAdditions>
   </iPhone>

Now the app is packaged correctly (even using Flex classes) and iTunes allow me to load the app on the device. Now the only problem is that my app looks completely white :-( Still need more investigation!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

yeah, better way always to join to Apple Developers program.

Let me know your output of 4th step:

```
pfi -package -target ipa-app-store -provisioning-profile /Path/to/Your/Provisioning/Profile -storetype pkcs12 -keystore /Path/to/Your/Certificate.p12 -storepass your_password YourApplication.ipa /Path/to/YourApplication-app.xml -C /Path/to/Your/SWF/and/Assets/Directory YourApplication.swf Default.png Icon_57.png
```

Thanks.

Comment: The step ends without error and i get the ipa application but iTunes doesn't allow me to upload the ipa into the device. Looking at the console i,ve founded the command used by the Flash Authoriting to' generate the ipa and it's almost the same

Comment: Maybe Flash Authoriting use a different version of tha packager, tomorrow i'll try